# XMP Profile and two RAMs of unequal speeds

Tags: memory, overclocking

I have a Corsair 2400Mhz 8GB DDR4 RAM (Single stick)  in my PC. Now if I buy another Corsair 3000MHz 8GB and install it in the next DIMM socket (and assuming it works) I believe both will be clocked to 2400 by default.

However if I choose XMP profile and set it to 3000 how the speeds will behave for individual sticks?

Will 3000 operate at stock speed of 3000 and 2400 gets overclocked to 3000?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use 1333 MHz and 1600 MHz RAM together?](https://superuser.com/questions/350891/can-i-use-1333-mhz-and-1600-mhz-ram-together)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**, the 2400mhz RAM could never be overclocked to 3000Mhz.

Long answer: The memory controller would operate at the lower speed by default to 2400Mhz. And from [this topic](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/two-different-size-ram-sticks-mixing-in-dual-channel.1954853/post-13463052):

> Asymmetric channel configuration will cause the board to operate memory in lower-performance interleaved mode and since the memory controller only supports one set of timings for all installed RAM, all your memory will have to follow the weakest DIMM's timings.

Besides, such an overclock of 600Mz would leave the computer unstable to be honest.

Comment: It’s not that easy. OP explicitly asked about XMP, which is technically overclocking.

Comment: But you can't combine different clock speeds, can you? @DanielB

Comment: You certainly can’t have two XMP profiles loaded.  One is certainly going to be running as the same frequency as the other and a 600 MHz overclock isn’t easily achieved

Comment: Yes, objectively it should use the highest XMP profile available. The problem I see is that XMP-enabled modules come with two XMP profiles and it’s in no way guaranteed the BIOS setup is equipped to deal with more than two profiles. However, I also never had mixed memory with XMP.